# When I join multiple sheets I get "Run-time error -2147467259 (80004005) Type mismatch in expression"

Tags: excel, vba, join

I am working on a reconciliation automation wherein I have to join multiple sheet data to produce an output. When I query single sheet without using joins it works fine, however when I join multiple sheets I get "Run-time error -2147467259 (80004005) Type mismatch in expression"

I am working on: Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.12827.20236) 64-bit

Here is my code for reference:

```
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Function Open_Connection() As Byte
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String

On Error GoTo Con_Error
strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
If Not con Is Nothing Then If con.State = 1 Then con.Close
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"


con.Open strCon

Open_Connection = 1

Exit Function

Con_Error:
    Open_Connection = 0
End Function

Private Function Supplier_Range() As String
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Dump_Supplier.Range("A" & Dump_Supplier.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1).End(xlUp).Row

If LastRow > 2 Then
    Supplier_Range = Dump_Supplier.Name & "$" & Replace(Dump_Supplier.Range("A2:P" & LastRow).Address, "$", "")
End If
End Function
Private Function Client_Range() As String
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Dump_Client.Range("A" & Dump_Client.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1).End(xlUp).Row

If LastRow > 2 Then
    Client_Range = Dump_Client.Name & "$" & Replace(Dump_Client.Range("A2:N" & LastRow).Address, "$", "")
End If

End Function
Function SQL_inv()

Dim Supplier_Range_txt As String
Dim Client_Range_txt As String

Supplier_Range_txt = Supplier_Range
If Len(Supplier_Range_txt) = 0 Then
    MsgBox prompt:="No Data Found On " & Dump_Supplier.Name & " Sheet.", Buttons:=vbCritical, Title:="Data Not Found"
    Exit Function
End If

Client_Range_txt = Client_Range
If Len(Client_Range_txt) = 0 Then
    MsgBox prompt:="No Data Found On " & Dump_Client.Name & " Sheet.", Buttons:=vbCritical, Title:="Data Not Found"
    Exit Function
End If

Open_Connection
If con.State = 0 Then
    MsgBox prompt:="Connection With Dataset Could Not Be Opened.", Buttons:=vbCritical, Title:="Connection Failure"
    Exit Function
End If

Dim strSQL As String
Dim Supplier_Inv As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim Client_Inv As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim Inv_Exact_Match As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim Inv_Match_With_Diff As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim Inv_Match_Amt As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim Inv_No_Match As New ADODB.Recordset

If Not Supplier_Inv Is Nothing Then If Supplier_Inv.State = 1 Then Supplier_Inv.Close
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & Supplier_Range_txt & "] WHERE [Standard Type] LIKE ""%Invoice%"";"
    strSQL = "SELECT A.[Pst DT], A.[Year], A.[Month], A.[Standard Type], A.[Type], A.[Invoice / Reference], A.[Amount], A.[Curr], A.[Debit Amount (+)], A.[Credit Amount (-)] FROM [" & Supplier_Range_txt & "] A  WHERE [Standard Type] LIKE ""%Invoice%"";"
    Supplier_Inv.Open Source:=strSQL, ActiveConnection:=con, CursorType:=adOpenKeyset, LockType:=adLockOptimistic

If Not Client_Inv Is Nothing Then If Client_Inv.State = 1 Then Client_Inv.Close
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & Client_Range_txt & "] WHERE [Standard Type] LIKE ""%Invoice%"";"
    strSQL = "SELECT B.[GL Date], B.[Year], B.[Month], B.[Standard Type], B.[Type], B.[Inv Check Num], B.[INR Amount], B.[Currency] FROM [" & Client_Range_txt & "] B  WHERE [Standard Type] LIKE ""%Invoice%"";"
    Client_Inv.Open Source:=strSQL, ActiveConnection:=con

Stop
If Not Inv_Exact_Match Is Nothing Then If Inv_Exact_Match.State = 1 Then Inv_Exact_Match.Close
    strSQL = "SELECT A.[Pst DT], A.[Year], A.[Month], A.[Standard Type], A.[Type], A.[Invoice / Reference], A.[Amount], A.[Curr], A.[Debit Amount (+)], A.[Credit Amount (-)], " & _
    "B.[GL Date], B.[Year], B.[Month], B.[Standard Type], B.[Type], B.[Inv Check Num], B.[INR Amount], B.[Currency] " & _
    "FROM [" & Supplier_Range_txt & "] A " & _
    "INNER JOIN [" & Client_Range_txt & "] B " & _
    "ON A.[Invoice / Reference] = B.[Inv Check Num] AND A.[Standard Type] = B.[Standard Type] " & _
    "WHERE A.[Standard Type] LIKE ""%Invoice%"" ;"
    'AND Abs(Abs(A.[Amount]) - Abs(B.[INR Amount])) <= Home.[Amount_Diff_Tolerance].Value
    Debug.Print strSQL
    Inv_Exact_Match.Open Source:=strSQL, ActiveConnection:=con, CursorType:=adOpenKeyset, LockType:=adLockOptimistic

'Debug.Print Supplier_Inv.GetString
Debug.Print Inv_Exact_Match.GetString

End Function
```

Here is what my join query produces:

```
SELECT A.[Pst DT], A.[Year], A.[Month], A.[Standard Type], A.[Type], A.[Invoice / Reference], A.[Amount], A.[Curr], A.[Debit Amount (+)], A.[Credit Amount (-)], B.[GL Date], B.[Year], B.[Month], B.[Standard Type], B.[Type], B.[Inv Check Num], B.[INR Amount], B.[Currency] FROM [SOA-Supplier$A2:P25581] A INNER JOIN [SOA-Client$A2:N23548] B ON A.[Invoice / Reference] = B.[Inv Check Num] AND A.[Standard Type] = B.[Standard Type] WHERE A.[Standard Type] LIKE "%Invoice%" ;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Without checking your vba-code, is there a reason why you use VBA instead of PowerQuery to get the data?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would want to use VBA for this one because there are many complexities involved and I feel more empowered with scripting.

Comment: After hitting the wall again and again, I found that ADO object model does not allow you to join sheets with multiple fields. There I created a one unique field on both the sheets and it worked fine then. This query stands resolved for me.